# wget command using brew in terminal (mac)

Tags: terminal, homebrew, wget

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off -P ./images/ -i./list.txt
./list.txt: No such file or directory
No URLs found in ./list.txt.
Converted links in 0 files in 0 seconds.
```

I downloaded and installed brew. Further, I installed wget and it's letting me download images one image at a time. However, when I tried the aforementioned command to download images from multiple urls, it's not doing anything. Can someone tell me what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`wget` is pretty lucid with description of issue

```
./list.txt: No such file or directory
```

apparently there is not file named `list.txt` inside current dir. Please trying giving full path to `list.txt`.

Comment: hey, it worked after I changed the pathname